# Unbind parameter

Tags: c#, linq, expression

all

I try to build a dynamic linq query by expression tree, below is my code

```
        Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter = c => c.isAdmin == false;
        Expression<Func<User, bool>> filterForExistUser = c => (c.isfreezed == null ? false : c.isfreezed) != true;
        Expression<Func<User, bool>> finalFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(filter.Body, filterForExistUser.Body), filter.Parameters);

        IQueryable<User> myusers = db.Users.AsQueryable<User>();
        MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { myusers.ElementType },
            myusers.Expression,
            finalFilter);
        IQueryable<User> results = myusers.Provider.CreateQuery<User>(whereCallExpression);
        foreach (User user in results)
            Console.WriteLine(user.UserName);
```

But system report "unding parameter c" error, how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what the error message is?

Comment: In the specified LINQ to Entities query does not bind the parameters c in the expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the parameters in the `filter` and `filterForExistUser` expressions share the same name, they both are referring to different symbols from different scopes.  Your new expression uses the parameter from the `filter` expression, but you left out the parameter for the `filterForExistUser`.  You must rewrite the expression so the same single parameter is used throughout the overall expression.

Here's a general purpose method you can use to combine the predicates:

```
Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> CombinePredicates<TSource>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> head,
    params Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>[] tail)
{
    var param = head.Parameters.Single();
    var body = tail.Aggregate(
        head.Body,
        (result, expr) => Expression.AndAlso(result,
            new SubstitutionVisitor
            {
                OldExpr = expr.Parameters.Single(),
                NewExpr = param,
            }.Visit(expr.Body)
        )
    );
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, param);
}

public class SubstitutionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression OldExpr { get; set; }
    public Expression NewExpr { get; set; }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return (node == OldExpr) ? NewExpr : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

The key is the `SubstitutionVisitor` which is used to substitute the "tail" paramters using the "head" parameter.

So your final filter becomes this:

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> finalFilter =
    CombinePredicates(filter, filterForExistUser);
```